# How to get object value from firebase inner class ValueEventListner in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I put the username value into MyName value so that I can get real time value because whenever I try to use it it shows Null pointer exception.

```
String username;

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  String userinfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
     username = userInfo.username;
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

}
});

String MyName = username;
```

Comment: Please reformat your code

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the myName variable first and then assign a value to it within the onDataChange callback, like this.

```
String username;
String myName;

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override 
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  String userinfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
     username = userInfo.username; 
     myName = username;
    //Call any method/operation that needs to use myName variable here
    ...
} 

@Override 
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

} 
});
```

Comment: but also it shows null pointer exception whenever i try to use myName value

Comment: It is because the onDataChange method is a callback from an asynchronous operation, hence you cannot use the myName variable until you have assigned a value to it (after the onDataChange is called).  Try calling the methods or operations that use myName after onDataChanged has been called.